# Avoid cross-site scripting DOM vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, jsp

my code is giving error in CAST at below line

1. input type="hidden" name="sid"
   value=<%=request.getParameter("sid"),
   can someone please tell how i can resolve this DOM vulnerability? please tell the modification in code. below is my code.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

   IAP

   ```
         <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css'>
         <link href="../atom-resources/css/sky-form.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="../atom-resources/css/custom-form.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="../atom-resources/css/awesomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

         <!-- FAVICONS -->
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../atom-resources/img/favicon-png.png" type="image/x-icon">
         <link rel="icon" href="../atom-resources/img/favicon-png.png" type="image/x-icon">

         <link href="../atom-resources/css/new-index-style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   ```

   <%@ taglib prefix="shiro" uri="http://shiro.apache.org/tags"%>
         
            <%@ include file="../atom-resources/shared/top.jsp" %>

   ```
        <%@ include file="../atom-resources/shared/side-menu.jsp" %>

        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg dashbard-1">
           <div class="row" >
              <div id="divHTML">
                 <div class="wrapper wrapper-content">
                    <!-- <div id="breadcrumb-container">
                       <span class="breadcrumb-parent">Robotic Assistance</span> > Triage
                       </div>-->
                    <div class="child-container">
                    <div class="sub-header">
                       Admin
                    </div>
                       <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12 rowBgcolor">
                          <div class="subHeader">General settings</div>

                       <shiro:hasAnyRoles name="Super Admin">
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                             <div class="icon-container">
                              <a href="customers.jsp">
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                   <i class="fa fa-user-secret custom-icon">
                                   <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                   </i>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   <a href="customers.jsp">Customer</a>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                       </shiro:hasAnyRoles>
                      <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-Users-ViewUser">
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                           <div class="icon-container">
                             <a href="users.jsp">
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                   <i class="fa fa-user custom-icon">
                                   <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                   </i>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   <a href="users.jsp">User</a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                          </shiro:hasPermission>
                          <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-Groups-ViewGroup">
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                          <div class="icon-container">
                               <a href="groups.jsp">
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                   <i class="fa fa-users custom-icon">
                                   <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                   </i>
                                </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   <a href="groups.jsp">Groups</a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             </shiro:hasPermission>
                         <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-Roles-ViewRole">
                          <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                          <div class="icon-container">
                                <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Roles')">
                                    <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                       <i class="fa glyphicon fa-newspaper-o custom-icon">
                                       <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                       </i>
                                   </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                    <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Roles')">Roles</a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                           </shiro:hasPermission>
                           <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-ManagePermission-ViewPermission">
                                  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                                  <div class="icon-container">
                                      <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Manage Permissions')">
                                           <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                               <i class="fa fa-lock custom-icon">
                                                <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                               </i>
                                           </div>
                                        </a>
                                    <div class="thumbText">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Manage Permissions')">Manage Permissions</a>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              </shiro:hasPermission>
                               <shiro:hasAnyRoles name="Super Admin">
                                  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                                      <div class="icon-container">
                                          <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Market Configuration')">
                                               <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                                   <i class="fa fa-database custom-icon">
                                                    <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                                   </i>
                                               </div>
                                            </a>
                                        <div class="thumbText">
                                            <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Market Configuration')">MarketPlace Configuration</a>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </shiro:hasAnyRoles>
                              <shiro:hasAnyRoles name="Super Admin">
                                 <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                                     <div class="icon-container">
                                         <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Heart Beat')">
                                              <div class="icon-wrapper">

                                                  <i class="fa fa-heartbeat custom-icon">
                                                   <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                                  </i>
                                              </div>
                                           </a>
                                       <div class="thumbText">
                                           <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Heart Beat')">Heartbeat</a>
                                       </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                              </shiro:hasAnyRoles>

                                 <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                                    <div class="icon-container">
                                        <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('ITSM Mapping')">
                                             <div class="icon-wrapper">

                                                 <i class="fa fa-delicious custom-icon">
                                                  <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                                 </i>
                                             </div>
                                          </a>
                                      <div class="thumbText">
                                          <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('ITSM Mapping')">ITSM Mapping</a>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                    <shiro:hasAnyRoles name="Super Admin,Admin">
                       <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12 rowBgcolor">
                          <div class="subHeader">Packages</div>

                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb" style="padding-left:0px; margin-left:0px;">
                                 <div class="icon-container">
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                   <i class="fa fa-calendar custom-icon">
                                   <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                   </i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   Event Management
                                </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                              <div class="icon-container">
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                   <span class="custom-icon">
                                       <img src="../atom-resources/img/automation1.png" style="width: 34px; height: 32px;">
                                   </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   Automation
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                              <div class="icon-container">
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                   <i class="fa fa-line-chart custom-icon">
                                   <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                   </i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   Analytics
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                       </div>
                       </shiro:hasAnyRoles>
                         <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12 rowBgcolor">
                          <div class="subHeader">Engine</div>
                          <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-EventRouting-EventRouting">
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb" style="padding-left:0px; margin-left:0px;">
                                 <div class="icon-container">
                                <a onclick="loadPage('Rules')">
                                    <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                       <i class="fa fa-calendar-o custom-icon">
                                       <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                       </i>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   <a onclick="loadPage('Rules')"> Event Routing </a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                             </shiro:hasPermission>
                             <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-TicketRoutingPolicies-TicketRouting">
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">

                              <div class="icon-container">
                               <a onclick="loadPage('Policies')">
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                   <i class="fa fa-ticket custom-icon">
                                   <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                   </i>
                                </div>
                               </a>
                                <div class="thumbText">
                                   <a onclick="loadPage('Policies')"> Ticket Routing</a>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                             </div>
                            </shiro:hasPermission>
                           <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-Configuration-ConfigurationView">
                            <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                               <div class="icon-container">
                                     <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Configuration')">
                                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                               <i class="fa fa-wrench  custom-icon">
                                                    <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                               </i>
                                          </div>
                                     </a>
                                    <div class="thumbText">
                                         <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('Configuration')">Configuration</a>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                             </shiro:hasPermission>
                             <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-PasswordVault-PasswordVaultView">
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                               <div class="icon-container">
                                     <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('PasswordVault')">
                                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                               <i class="fa fa-key  custom-icon">
                                                    <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                               </i>
                                          </div>
                                     </a>
                                    <div class="thumbText">
                                         <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('PasswordVault')">Password Vault</a>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>
                             </shiro:hasPermission>
                              <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-ApplianceManagement-ApplianceManagementView">
                                  <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                                   <div class="icon-container">
                                         <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('ApplianceMaintenance')">
                                              <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                                   <i class="fa fa-server  custom-icon">
                                                        <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                                   </i>
                                              </div>
                                         </a>
                                        <div class="thumbText">
                                             <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('ApplianceMaintenance')">Appliance Management</a>
                                        </div>
                                   </div>
                                 </div>
                            </shiro:hasPermission>

                             <!--<div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                               <div class="icon-container">
                                   <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('UserBusinessService')">
                                       <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                           <i class="fa fa-sitemap custom-icon">
                                           <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                           </i>
                                       </div>
                                   </a>
                                   <div class="thumbText">
                                       <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('UserBusinessService')">User Business Service Mapping</a>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                             </div>-->
                             <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-ValidatePatternWorkflow-ValidatePattern">
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">

                               <div class="icon-container">
                                     <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('validate')">
                                          <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                               <i class="fa fa-check-square-o  custom-icon">
                                                    <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                               </i>
                                          </div>
                                     </a>
                                    <div class="thumbText">
                                         <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('validate')">Validation Pattern</a>
                                    </div>
                               </div>

                             </div>
                             </shiro:hasPermission>
                              <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-2 col-xs-4 circleThumb">
                                 <div class="icon-container">
                                       <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('AuditLog')">
                                            <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                                 <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o custom-icon">
                                                      <span class="fix-editor">&nbsp;</span>
                                                 </i>
                                            </div>
                                       </a>
                                      <div class="thumbText">
                                           <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('AuditLog')">Audit Log</a>
                                      </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>


                           </div>

                       </div>
                           <input type="hidden" name="sid" value=<%=request.getParameter("sid")%> >
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>

    <%@ include file="../atom-resources/shared/bottom.html" %>
       <script src="../atom-resources/js/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
       <script src="../atom-resources/js/jsviews.js"></script>
       <script src="../atom-resources/js/jquery.formatDateTime.js"></script>
        <!-- Configuration Page Js file -->
         <script src="../atom-resources/js/Configuration.js"></script>
       <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#admin-li').addClass('active');

           loadPage = function(pageName){
               $('.side-sub-menu').removeClass('Active');
               if(pageName == "Customer")
               {
                   $("#customer-li").addClass("Active");
                   $("#divHTML").load("_customers.html");
               }

               else if(pageName == "Roles") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                   $("#divHTML").load("roles.jsp");
                   $("#roles-li").addClass("Active");
               }
                else if(pageName == "Manage Permissions") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                   $("#ManagePermissions-li").addClass("Active");
                   $("#divHTML").load("manage-permissions.jsp");
               }
               else if(pageName == "Rules")
               {
                $('#Engine-Rules-li').addClass('Active');
                   $("#divHTML").load("policyManagement.jsp");
               }

               else if(pageName == "ApplianceMaintenance")
                                 {
                                    $('#Engine-ApplianceMaintenance-li').addClass('Active');
                                    $("#divHTML").load("Appliance-Maintenance.jsp");
                                 }
              else if(pageName == "Policies")
               {
                  $('#Engine-Policies-li').addClass('Active');
                  /*$("#divHTML").load("_routing-home.html");*/
                  $("#divHTML").load("TicketRouting.jsp");
               }

               else if(pageName == "Configuration") {
                   $("#Engine-Configuration-li").addClass("Active");
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");

                   $("#divHTML").load("configuration.jsp");
               }
               else if(pageName == "Market Configuration") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");

                   $("#divHTML").load("Mp-Configuration.jsp");
               }

                else if(pageName == "Heart Beat") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                   $("#HeartBeat-li").addClass("Active");
                   $("#divHTML").load("heartbeat.jsp");
               }

                else if(pageName == "ITSM Mapping") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                   $("#itsm-mapping-li").addClass("Active");
                   $("#divHTML").load("itsm-mapping.jsp");
               }

               else if(pageName == "PasswordVault") {
                     <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-PasswordVault-ConsoleEdit">
                                 PasswordVaultConsoleEdit=true;
                     </shiro:hasPermission>
                     <shiro:hasPermission name="Admin-PasswordVault-ConsoleDelete">
                                 PasswordVaultConsoleDelete=true;
                     </shiro:hasPermission>
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                    $('#Engine-PasswordVault-li').addClass('Active');
                   $("#divHTML").load("Password-Vault.jsp");
               }
                else if(pageName == "ApplianceMaintenance") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");

                   $("#divHTML").load("Appliance-Maintenance.jsp");
               }
                else if(pageName == "AuditLog") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                    $("#audit").addClass("Active");
                   $("#divHTML").load("audit-log.jsp");
               }
               else if(pageName == "LogPolicy") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                    $("#log-policy").addClass("Active");
                   $("#divHTML").load("log-policy.jsp");
               }
                else if(pageName == "LogSync") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");
                    $("#log-sync").addClass("Active");
                   $("#divHTML").load("log-sync.jsp");
               }
               else if(pageName == "validate") {
                $('#Engine-Validate-li').addClass('Active');
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");

                   $("#divHTML").load("validate.jsp");
               }

               /*else if(pageName == "UserBusinessService") {
                   $("#ulReports").addClass("in");

                   $("#divHTML").load("user-business-service.jsp");
               }*/
           }
       });
       </script>
   ```

Comment: Don't know much about jsp but `request.getParameter("sid")` looks like it would get a get / post request variable.... you should never render arbitrary request data to the page without sanitizing it first.

Comment: yes i understood this thing. can some one please tell how should i pass it then

Comment: So what is your issue ? Do you have an error ? You have a [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) ?

Comment: CAST saying Avoid cross-site scripting DOM vulnerabilities

Comment: can someone please tell the solution